# Google Scripts to Run from Owner's Account

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I have a script that fetches events from my shared calendar and displays the events details in my shared spreadsheet. However, when other people try run the script, the script is unable to find the calendar because it is looking for the calendar against the user who triggers the script.

Solution: Make a Web-App and then let the user trigger a small script that runs the main script i.e. the Web-App (as suggested by [Michael Aaron Safyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136540/michael-aaron-safyan)).

Current Problem:
I've made the web-app, and [using this method](http://www.jellybend.com/2012/12/18/trigger-updates-between-master-slave-spreadsheets/), my Web-App is *successfully*  invoked when I open `URL?wake=up` in a browser.. seems all is good there.

**However**, The 2nd part (trigger script) does not seem to get the Web-App to run. Its using `UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL?wake=up");` yet it fails to run the Web-App.

Need guidance:

***How to trigger the Web-App from a function.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Scripts can be run in various different modes. This is documented at [Google Apps Script: Permissions and types of Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts). If you publish the application as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) or as a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), then you can have the script execute under the account of the creator instead of the accessing user's account. For this specific case, it sounds like you want to use a trigger that runs `onOpen`.

Comment: Yes I also believe onOpen will work, but I want to provide a button to call the script as well, so the user can manipulate the dates for which the events are fetched.

Comment: This is doable, but requires separate scripts.... one that runs under your account that you expose as a web service and a separate one that runs under the user's account that invokes that web service.

Comment: I've made the web-app.. only thing remains is to call the script from a different (small) script, and then let use invoke the small script..

Comment: I've made the web-app..
and following this method [link](http://www.jellybend.com/2012/12/18/trigger-updates-between-master-slave-spreadsheets/) my webapp now triggers when I open its `URL?wake=up` .. seems all is good there, but the 2nd part _(trigger script)_ does not seem to get the web-app to run. Its using `UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL?wake=up");` yet it fails to run the web-app.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Make a Web-App and then let the user trigger a small script that runs the main script i.e. the Web-App (as suggested by Michael Aaron Safyan).